# Running bash file in background process issue

Tags: php, linux, websocket

I created a simple bash file to run a php file like this:

ws.sh

```
!#/bin/bash
php -q /var/www/htdocs/server.php
```

server.php

```
<?php
// prevent the server from timing out
set_time_limit(0);
session_start();
// include the web sockets server script (the server is started at the far bottom of this file)
require 'class.PHPWebSocket.php';

// when a client sends data to the server
function wsOnMessage($clientID, $message, $messageLength, $binary) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    // check if message length is 0
    if ($messageLength == 0) {
        $Server->wsClose($clientID);
        return;
    }
    
    $_SESSION['currentId'] = $message;
}

// when a client connects
function wsOnOpen($clientID){
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );
    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has connected. ");
    $data = array('connectionId' => $clientID,'msg'=>'Connected');
    $Server->wsSend($clientID, json_encode($data));
    
}

// when a client closes or lost connection
function wsOnClose($clientID, $status) {
    global $Server;
    $ip = long2ip( $Server->wsClients[$clientID][6] );

    $Server->log( "$ip ($clientID) has disconnected. sess = ".$session_id );
    
}

// start the server
$Server = new PHPWebSocket();
$Server->bind('message', 'wsOnMessage');
$Server->bind('open', 'wsOnOpen');
$Server->bind('close', 'wsOnClose');

$Server->wsStartServer('server-ip-here', 81);

?>
```

then on my terminal I will run the bash file into background

```
./ws.sh &
```

Now, the problem is if the bash file running on the background the client was not able to connect to my websocket and returns an error "CONNECTION REFUSED" but if its a normal running (not background) I have to problem connecting to it. Any idea? Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already figure it out. I just change my php command line to:

```
php -q /var/www/htdocs/server.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```